# Renaming getter on renaming instance member?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, refactoring, getter, getter-setter

In Eclipse one can generate a getter for an instance member, it then looks like this:

```
private String abc;

// generated using Source - Generate Getters and Setters
public String getAbc() {
    return abc;
}
```

Now when I rename `abc` to `def`, the getter also has to be renamed to `getDef()`. This however isn't done automatically by Eclipse. Is there any way to also do this using Eclipse? Any plugin for such things?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the "quick rename" only. When you started the renaming of a field using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, either hit the small triangle at the right of the popup and select "Open rename dialog", or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> a second time. You will then get a rename refactoring dialog, where renaming the getter/setter methods are shown as additional options.